# solving the ODE $y''-3y'+2y=\sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following second order linear ODE with constant coefficient : 
$$y''(x)-3y'(x)+2y(x)=\sin(x)$$
with $y'(x)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$ and $y$ a function defined on an real interval $I$. $y$ is obviously differentiable on $I$. I would like to find the solution of this ODE. For this, I first compute the characteristic polynomial of this equation : 
$$r^2-3r+2=0$$
which can be factorized as 
$$(r-1)(r-2)=0$$
Hence, the roots of the characteristic equation are $r_1=1$ and $r_2=2$ and one can right the solution the the homogeneous equation associated to the ODE $y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$ with $c_1$ and $c_2$ constant and real coefficient. Now, I need to find the particular solution $y_p$ to the problem. Because the second member is a $\sin$, I state that :
$$y_p(t)=A\cos x+B\sin x$$
with $A$ and $B$ constant real numbers. We have : 
$$y_p'(x)=-A\sin x +B\cos x$$
and 
$$y_p''(x)=-A\cos x -B \sin x$$
by substitution, I find that $A=1/4$ and $B=1/4$. Then, the general solution the ODE is : 
$$y(t)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}+\frac{1}{4}(\cos x + \sin x)$$
I would like to know whereas what I did is correct or not. I don't really know If I can write $y_p$ as a combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Have you tried to check if $y(t)$ found satisfies your initial equation?

Comment: You write that you find $A=\frac{1}{4}=B$, but that is not correct...

Comment: writing $y_p$ as a combination of sin and cos is the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)

Comment: Could you edit the "by substitution" step into your question so we can see where your arithmetic went wrong? I wonder if the change in order of trigonometric functions in $y_p^\prime$ led to a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-a \cos (x)-b \sin (x)-3 \left[b \cos (x)-a \sin (x)\right]+2 \left[a \cos (x)+b \sin (x)\right]=\sin(x)$

simplify and collect terms:

$$(3 a+b) \sin (x)+(a-3 b) \cos (x)=\sin(x)$$

thus we must solve:

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
     3a+b=1\hfill \\
     a-3b=0 \hfill
     \end{gathered}  \right.$$

which gives:

$$a= \frac{3}{10};\;b=\frac{1}{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

your answer is ok for the method, but A=B=1/4 is wrong, please recalculate and check by putting your result in the equation.  If sin(x) is not a solution of the homogenous de your yp is the common and right method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$ as you do. I find the coefficients must be different, that is $A = 3/10$ and $B= 1/10$.

Be consistent with your notations: sometimes you write $y(t) = \cos x$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with coefficients in the [PI](http://www.mscroggs.co.uk/teaching/6103-lecture23.pdf), it's perhaps easier to write $\sin x$ as $\frac{1}{2i}\sum_\pm\pm\exp\pm ix$, then seek $c_\pm$ satisfying $(D^2-3D+2)c_\pm e^{\pm ix}=e^{\pm ix}$ with $D:=\tfrac{d}{dx}$. Clearly, $c_\pm=\frac{1}{1\mp 3i}=\frac{1\pm3i}{10}$, so$$\frac{1}{2i}\sum_\pm\pm c_\pm\exp\pm ix=\frac{1}{20}\sum_\pm(3\mp i)\exp\pm ix=\frac12\Re(3-i)\exp ix=\frac{3\cos x+\sin x}{10}.$$